# Mocking a gcp pubsub object in Node js. with jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, google-cloud-platform, jestjs

I am trying to write unit tests for GCP cloud functions.Below is the code snippet that I am trying to test.

```js
//index.js
const {PubSub} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');
const pubsub = new PubSub();

exports.myFunction = functions.runWith(RUNTIME_OPTS).https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  //pubsubbody = generated..

  //some logic

  await pubsub.topic(topicname).publish(pubsubBody, {
    platform: body.platform,
    environment: body.environment,
    event: !!event ? event : 'unknown',
  });
});
```

I was able to test myFunction logic using firebase-functions-test library.
I did something like this

```
//test.js
const fft = require('firebase-functions-test')();
const funcs = require('../../index');

describe('function to test viewAddRequestedProxy', () => {
  const wrapped = fft.wrap(funcs.viewAddRequestedProxy);

  // simple logic test.
  test('NullDataTest', async () => {
    const result = await wrapped(null, null);
    expect(result).toStrictEqual({output: 'xyz'});
  });
});
```

Now I want to test the line where I make a pubsub call inside my function.
I tried many things but I am really new to node.js as well as mocking objects in general.

I am not understanding how can I mock the pubsub object inside my index.js and check if it is publishing message or not.

```js
await pubsub.topic(topicname).publish(pubsubBody, {
  platform: body.platform,
  environment: body.environment,
  event: !!event ? event : 'unknown',
});
```

I am confused if I need to export my pubsub object and access it test.js or not. I tried this but for some reason `"module.exports = { pubsub: pubsub };"` was not working for me.
I also tried to create a mock in test.js using spyOn

```js
const {PubSub} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');
const singleAdd = (PubSub) => {
  PubSub.topic;
};

test('spyOn .toBeCalled()', (object, method) => {
  const somethingSpy = jest.spyOn(PubSub, 'topic');
  somethingSpy();
  const topic = PubSub.topic('abc');
  expect(somethingSpy).toBeCalled();
});
```

Also tried manual mocks although I am not sure if I need this. By creating a **Mocks** folder but nothing seems to work.

Any help will be appreciated. I think I am completely off track.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to mock a node lib you need to put a file inside `__mocks__/lib-name/index.js` which will mimic the **real interface**.

In your case, put a `pubsub.js` file inside `__mocks__/@google-cloud/`.

```
//pubsub.js

class PubSubMock {
  static mockInstances = [];

  static clearAllMocks() {
    PubSubMock.mockInstances.forEach((instance) =>
      Object.getOwnPropertyNames(
        instance.constructor.prototype
      ).forEach((method) => method.mockClear())
    );
    
    PubSubMock.mockInstances.length = 0;
  }

  constructor() {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.constructor.prototype).forEach((method) => {
      spyOn(this, method).and.callThrough();
    });

    PubSubMock.mockInstances.push(this);
  }

  topic(topic) {
    // you can implement here the logic
    return this;
  }

  publish(body, obj) {
    return this;
  }
}

module.exports.PubSub = PubSubMock;
```

Jest will make sure that each require of `'@google-cloud/pubsub'` will be mapped to that mock file.

The mock implementation of the `PubSub` class is auto spying on all of the class methods, this way you can test if some method is called and with what args.

The problem is that your production code creates a new instance of `PubSub` and not exposing it, therefore you can't get a reference for it. A small trick is to expose a static property which will hold all created instances, and will be exposed by `PubSub.mockInstances`.

```js
const {PubSub} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');
const funcs = require('../../index');

test('spyOn .toBeCalled()', (object, method) => {
  funcs() // call for you real code
  const mockInstance = PubSub.mockInstances[0];
  expect(mockInstance.topic).toHaveBeenCalledWith('arg1');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: However when I run the entire suite now I get the below error "Error: expect(received).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)" . I did a console.log on mockInstance and mockInstance.topic and I see " PubSubMock { randomVar: 0.9313179947987984 }" and "[Function: topic]". Another weird thing is when I run only the specific test case and not the entire test suite I can see that topic is of type spy..
 PubSubMock {
      randomVar: 0.635109508350415,
      topic: [Function: spy] { .........
but now I get. "Async callback was not invoked within the 30000 ms"

Comment: You probably need to make some moke implementation of the pubsub methods. For example, if one of the methods get a callback, you need to decide how and when you call it.

Comment: dear felix, thank you for your response. I returned a promise from the publish function. However, the problem still persisted and I found that the test case would run fine till the end and then won't exit. I just added a callback done() at the end of the test case to indicate the test is over. One more issue now if you can help. I am not able to refresh the mock data because of which the count of methods is always increasing if I do  expect(mockInstance.topic).toHaveBeenCalled(1) it only works for the first test case. I have tried jest.clearallmocks, jest.resetallmocks but its not working.

Comment: You need to call `mockClear` on each spied method. I've updated my mock implementation to allow easy clean up, just add call to `PubSub.clearAllMocks()` it will reset the counts, and remove created instances

Answer (score -1):

ReferenceError: spyOn is not defined
when using above method to mock pubsub